# Mapstruct: how to convert a integer in a object to a integer

Tags: java, mapstruct

How can i use Java Mapstruct to map a User to UserDto?

```
public class User {
    private Integer idUser;
    private Job job;
}

public class Job {
    private Integer idJob;
    private String name;
}

public class UserDto {
    private Integer idUser;
    private Integer jobId;
}
```

Do a simple method like below didn't work because it's not mapping user.job.user atribute to userDto.jobId atribute

```
UserDto userToUserDto(User user);
```

That's is a usual problem when you need to pass a ORM entity to a DTO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `@Mapping` attribute above your `userToUserDto` method:

```
@Mapping(source = "job.idJob", target = "jobId")
UserDto userToUserDto(User user);
```

Note that `source = "job.idJob"` refers to the field `idJob` of the field `job` in the `User` source object, and `target = "jobId"` to the field `jobId` of the `UserDto` target object.

See the [MapStruct Reference Guide](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/) for more detailed information on how to use MapStruct.